# Uncaught syntax error during photo upload using AjaxFileUpload

Tags: ajax

```html
if(myData)
   {
    $('.overlay_content').html('<img src="'+baseurl+'resource/img/loading.gif" width="30"> &nbsp;LOADING');
    $('#loader_overlay').fadeIn(100);
      $.ajaxFileUpload({
      url:baseurl+"invoice_settings/manage/post_settings/",
      secureuri  :false,
      fileElementId :'invoice_logo',
      dataType  : 'JSON',
      data   : myData,
      success : function (data)
      {
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
                             $('.overlay_content').html('<img src="'+baseurl+'resource/img/tick.jpg" width="30"> &nbsp;Updation Successfull<br/>');
         $('#loader_overlay').fadeOut(5000);
         $("#settings_form").data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();
      }

                         handleError: function( s, xhr, status, e ) {
                        // If a local callback was specified, fire it
                        if ( s.error ) {
                            s.error.call( s.context || window, xhr, status, e );
                        }

                        // Fire the global callback
                        if ( s.global ) {
                            (s.context ? jQuery(s.context) : jQuery.event).trigger( "ajaxError", [xhr, s, e] );
                        }
                    }
     });
      
   }
```

This is my js file. when I run my page the data is not uploading and it returns uncaught syntax error. I added handle error function after getting the error "jQuery.handleError is not a function". After adding handleError function now its returning this error.please help me

Comment: Do you wanna to use ajaxFileUpload or is that ok to use $.post also?

Comment: @Subbu: Im working in codeigniter and I want to use AjaxFileUpload

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of answer available over internet. whenever you stuck do initial workaround as suggested.

How to use ajax in codeigniter: https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-jquery-ajax-post/

Sample code:

```
$('form').on('submit', uploadFiles);

// Catch the form submit and upload the files
function uploadFiles(event)
{
  event.stopPropagation(); // Stop stuff happening
    event.preventDefault(); // Totally stop stuff happening

// START A LOADING SPINNER HERE

// Create a formdata object and add the files
var data = new FormData();
$.each(files, function(key, value)
{
    data.append(key, value);
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'submit.php?files',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false, // Don't process the files
    contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
        {
            // Success so call function to process the form
            submitForm(event, data);
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle errors here
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        // Handle errors here
        console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
        // STOP LOADING SPINNER
    }
});
}
```

Comment: is this useful or any concerns?